# Is video considered a Tensor?

Tags: video, tensor

A sampled single dimensional signal is a vector.
A sampled image is a matrix.
Is video considered a rank-3 tensor since it is a set of images stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Tensor is not just a higher rank array, it must be independent of the coordinate system. In your case I'd say that a video is a rank-3 array.

Comment: So, by independent of coordinate system, do you mean that a tensor does not have a basis?  Sorry, brand new to Tensors!

Comment: Tensor is used for multi-way array; not for the tensor field. So it is just a generic name for multi-way array in machine learning community (search: tensor factorization). So, from this point, yes video is a tensor, it is an array of dimension $m\times n\times 3$.

Comment: @Sturm I think you might be mixing up the terms "tensor" and "tensor field". I think depending on the field you are in, these are sometimes used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

yes - a video signal would be considered 3rd order tensor.

scalars are 0-order tensors, vectors are 1st order tensors, matrices are 2nd order tensor,  data volumes are 3rd order tensors and so on for multi-dimensional arrays.